# Protobuf GTFS Realtime invalid wire-type

Tags: protobuf-net, gtfs

I have built my c# classes using the tool at https://protogen.marcgravell.com/ from the gtfs-realtime.proto file at https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime.proto

Im pulling in a feed from http://transitfeeds.com/p/king-county-metro/445/source using the below:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://transitfeeds.com/p/king-county-metro/445/source");
FeedMessage feed = Serializer.Deserialize<FeedMessage>(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

but im hit with invalid wire-type - cant for the life of me see whats wrong, the classes are up to date generated from the latest proto file - are there issues when the request comes from a url?

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to parse the plain text in the end?

Answer (score 1):

http://transitfeeds.com/p/king-county-metro/445/source is a plain text snapshot of the GTFS-RT feed, but the tool is expecting an actual Protobuf GTFS-RT feed.

In this case, it looks like you'll need to [request an API key from SoundTransit](https://www.soundtransit.org/help-contacts/business-information/open-transit-data-otd/otd-downloads) to use the original feed.

Comment: Thanks - you are correct - it works fine with an actual pb file. I might need a rethink then.

Comment: Is there any way to recover that data from plain text?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two different formats in protobuf; the *original* format was binary. Later, a secondary json encoding was added that works with the same DSL. But being JSON it is *far* less efficient than the default binary format.

Now; protobuf-net **only implements** the binary encoding. It *looks* like your feed is JSON, in which case it isn't going to work well with protobuf-net.

The google implementation supports both the binary and JSON formats, if that helps (protobuf-net is simply a separate implementation of the protobuf specification).

Comment: @ChrisMarais agreed, but it *certainly* isn't protobuf binary :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MWRl.png - of the two, it is closer to JSON, but yes: looking again, no JSON serializer will touch that